# Transient path is closed in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be a random path and a.s. dense and a.s. transient in the closed upper half plane $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$.

Why do we then have that $\gamma[0,\infty)$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$ and hence that $\gamma[0,\infty)=\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ ?

Thanks

Comment: What does a.s. mean here?

Comment: For example for transient: $\mathbb{P}[\lim_{t\to\infty} |\gamma(t)|=\infty]=1$

Comment: But we are given a single path $\gamma$ here. I don't understand how we can have probabilities showing up anywhere.

Comment: It is a random path, it is about Schramm Loewner evolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "transient" means that $\gamma(t)\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$:

There's probably a more elegant way to say this: Suppose $\gamma(t_n)\to z$. Then $t_n$ does not tend to infinity. So there is a convergent subsequence $t_{n_j}\to t$. Hence $\gamma(t)=z$.

Comment: Why do we need the convergence subsequence here and not just the sequence $t_n$? Is it possible to have a nonconvergence sequence $t_n$ for which $\gamma(t_n)\to z$ holds?

Comment: ??? Certainly it's _possible_ to have a divergent sequence $t_n$ with $\gamma(t_n)\to z$. A lot of things are possible. We need to show that there exists $t$ with $\gamma(t)=z$. If the sequence $t_n$ does not converge then it's _possible_ that $\gamma(t_n)\to z$, but saying it's _possible_ doesn't prove that it is actually so. On the other hand there _is_ a convergent subsequence $t_{n_j}$.

Comment: I understand that we use Bolzano Weierstrass to be sure. However, I can not imagine that it is possible to have a divergent sequence $t_n$ with $\gamma(t_n)\to z$.

Comment: If $\gamma$ is both transient and dense it must be highly non-injective. Say $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$, and let $(t_n)$ be the sequence $0,1,0,1,\dots$.

Comment: Ofcourse, thanks. I thought of an increasing sequence, but that is indeed not given.